# Git Bash Error - bashrc not a valid identifier

Tags: git-bash

When I open Git Bash, I get this on my navigator.

```
$ source .bashrc bash:
export: `Path/c/Users/User/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/User/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64:/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3/scripts:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/anaconda3:/c/Users/User/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/anaconda3:/c/Users/User/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/anaconda3:/c/Users/User/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/anaconda3:/c/Users/User/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/anaconda3:/c/Users/User/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3:/c/Users/User/Anaconda3/Scripts': not a valid identifier
```

I don't know how to solve it as I am totally new in this and I was following some instructions to setup Anaconda and Git Bash and use python through

[image: reference]

Comment: What are the contents of your ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Git for Windows uses `%USERPROFILE%` as `$HOME` in a Git bash session.

Check if you have a `C:\Users\<me>\.bashrc`, and if yes, start by renaming it, for testing.

Then, if `git bash` works better, re-create it and add back its content line by lilne, to determine the one which causes the error message.